# Change the GLPaint brush size outside of PaintingView.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, size

I need to change GLPaint's brush size outside of the PaintingView.m view. How can I do this? I was first thinking about using an NSNotification to transfer the value to the PaintingView.m controller - although from there I'm not entirely sure what to do as the brush size is defined in the .h file?

Some thoughts and a small example if possible please.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSUserDefaults` For store size value of brush and pass this `NSUserDefaults` value in .m file. Now, you can change your NSUserDefaults value from anywhere in application and also in delegate file as well using Notification. So, Whatever size store in `NSUserDefaults` that will automatically come in .m file.

Hope, this may help you..

Comment: But then how can I change `#define` in the PaintingView.m controller? :)